# What are the benifits of loading c modules (plugin) dynamically by running a C based application

Tags: c, linux, plugins, operating-system, embedded

I got advised to decompose some parts of my C application in modules (plugin) which get loaded dynamically when the application is running. I can see only the benefits of this practise when the application is relied on some OS modules which are not loaded by default.

What are the disadvantages  when predefining  a fix number of small in size plugins (OS related and Application related) and link them to the application statically?

Comment: Are you talking about the dlopen family?

Comment: Do you mean "plug-in" or simply *shared library*? They are not the same thing.

Comment: many sources refer to a shared library as a plug-in. But I mean in this context shared library using dlopen family

Comment: If you use the dlopen family instead of linking at compile time with the shared library, you can gracefully handle the case when a library is missing or it exists but is a different version. In that case you can resort to other solutions or at least display useful help so the user can fix the problem.

Comment: Where this is useful is if you want to support someone adding functionality without requiring recompilation of the main program. For example, adding decoding of a new protocol to a sniffer. He would create a new shared library using a provided template and then you can tell the program to load the new decoder by name. This is what I'd call a plug-in.